# Qt for android: change the application icon

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, application-icon

How would I change the icon of Qt project targeted for android so that the launcher of application has this icon?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should create an Android manifest file and edit it in Qt Creator. Go to **Projects > Build Android APK > Details**

Now Select **Create Templates** to create the manifest file and to open it in editor :

[image]

As shown in the picture, you can set three versions of icons for your application with low, medium, and high DPI values, from left to right.

This new way of making an android manifest file is available since Qt 5.4 along Qt Creator 3.3. There used to be a **Create AndroidManifest.xml** button in **Projects->Run->Deploy** in previous versions.

Comment: could you please tell what icon sizes have to be for all the three icons?

Comment: @Nulik Usually the standard size for low, medium and high are 36 x 36, 48 x 48 and 72 x 72 respectively.

Comment: but this wouldn't be enough for 4K screens? or would it?

Comment: @Nulik Yeah it would not be enough for 4K. If you want to cover 4K, you should have larger icons for example 96 x 96, 144 x 144, 192 x 192. For low resolution displays they would be down-scaled by Android to match the expected size.

Answer (score 1):

Open Run settings of your project and select Create AndroidManifest.xml, then you'll be able to modify the manifest which should include stuff like the icon.

Refer to this:http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.2/creator-deploying-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [this article](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/23/anatomy-of-a-qt-5-for-android-application/) about anatomy of a Qt 5 for Android application. You should attach to your project file `AndroidManifest.xml`, where you can define [icon of application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#iconlabel).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to update this a bit:
Using the AndroidManifest.xml, you can add  `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcherx"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcherx_round"` to  `<application ...` .

You can [generate the icons](https://dev.to/_s_farias/how-to-create-adaptive-icons-for-android-using-android-studio-459h) simply in the android studio and add them to your project's android folder (ie: /android/res/[mipmap-hdpi]/[ic_launcherx.png] )

So this adds an icon and a rounded icon to the application. The interesting part, however, is the name; leaving the name `@mipmap/ic_launcher` will cause a `"Error: Duplicate resource"` ... So don't forget to change it.
After that, a normal build should succeed =)

Answer (score 1):

**It is even more simplified in the QT Creator 4.12:**

In the latest Qt Creator one is able to click on **projects > Build > "Create Templates"**

[image]

After that you can edit the Manifest as @Nejat explained:

[image]

Cheers!