# can I build against newer android SDKs without excluding owners of older phones?

Tags: android, qt

so I'm using QT to develop an app for Android, and according to Sophos Mobile Security this app is "Built for outdated Android versions: this app doesn't support recent android security features. the app was built for an older version of android"

in qt creator I have android-25 set as the android build sdk (which I wouldn't consider old after all, it's 7.1.1 nougat)

how can I make this warning go away? Is there a way to build my app for a newer version of android without excluding users from using it? (I have 7.1.1, and at least I want to use my app)

thank you for your response in advance.

**EDIT:**

seems like there are (at least?) 3 spots where I can set an SDK version:

- minimum required sdk, as seen on the screenshot here: [Qt for android: change the application icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423150/qt-for-android-change-the-application-icon)
- target SDK version, as seen on the screenshot above
- this was the only one I was aware an hour ago: projects->build->build android apk->android build sdk

what they govern, how to set them? should they be the same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android suggests you use the latest sdk version for `targetSdkVersion` and for build-tools version (they have to match). In fact, Google Play now requires you to target at least SDK 26.  This will not prevent older devices from running app. Actually it will be more problematic for newer devices, as you are stating that app has been fully tested and can run on newer devices, and does not need backward compatibility. See https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk for more details.
As for `minSdkVersion`, that is what will determine the earliest devices supported, and you should try to keep it as low as you can, and as 95-99% of your users.