# pyqtdeploy: how to set application icon for Android?

Tags: python, android, pyqt5, qt5, pyqtdeploy

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/@Lola_Dam/packaging-pyqt-application-using-pyqtdeploy-for-both-linux-and-android-32ac7824708b) howto to build an Android application with Python3 and Qt5. *Nearly* everything works fine but somehow I cannot find out how to set the application icon. In the [documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/) I could not find anything neither..

And just in case you know PyQtDeploy anyway.. how do I set the build mode from `debug` to `release`?

**Backround:**

`pyqtdeploy-build` creates the whole build-folder for Android (which contains all resources and `AndroidManifest.xml`) from scratch. Up to now I did not find a way to tell which icon to use. I would expect an option in the pyqtdeploy interface but there seems to be none..

Comment: To the downvoter: could you please elaborate on your thoughts? Do you know `pyqtdeploy` and find it easy to accomplish, what I'm asking for?

Comment: I guess this just deploys a normal android application right? Shouldn't you then put the icon inside the proper `res` folders of the application, specify it in the `AndroidManifest` and once you hit the deploy command it should package with it.

Comment: As I just wrote - there is no `AndroidManifest.xml` or `res` folder in the first place. Both are being created by running `pyqtdeploy-build` which you run every time you want to build your application. This is why I was hoping you can specify the app icon in your sources..

Comment: oh I see. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423150/qt-for-android-change-the-application-icon) there should be one, but I must confess I never actually coded a Qt project or even used pyQt. Maybe the link helps you out. Sorry if it doesn't.

Comment: Can you write a blog or make a video for developing for android? I followed the medium post but It didn't help me.

Comment: I'll do my very best - but allow some units of procrastination to pass :)

Comment: @Infinyte7: I don't know if you get notified - let me know. I now managed to build the demo based on pyqtdeploy-3.1.0 at least for Linux now, Android is coming. See https://projects.om-office.de/frans/pyqt5_tools Unfortunately this setup has been far more difficult to set up then with Qt5.12 and pyqtdeploy-2.4 due to badly documented dependencies. If you see this comment have a look in the `docker/setup*.sh` files to see how to meet requirements for up to Qt5.15.2. Android is coming soon - maybe this weekend

Comment: @frans  Using @ I get notified. I haven't viewed your earlier comments. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I have never tried it but [@Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344487/fred) in comment above mentioned [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28186554) in Qt Creator - maybe it will work

**Edit end**

PyQtDeploy is designed for Python code and resources management. App icon is an Android framework thing, so you have to do it Android way - create resource in `res` folder and reference it in `Android manifest`.

You can automate the process though - you may create simple bash script that does the thing or one more Python build script with the same purpose - it takes icon from your location moves it to `res` folder and alters previously generated manifest with the correct reference in form of `android:icon="@drawable/your_logo_name"`.

At least I was doing it like that.

And as a recommendation - if you want to use Python to develop under Android(and cross platform) use [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) it is much more mature, supportable and complete with much bigger community. It is much faster and has more libs also.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you find one res name folder if not create it their and refer to manifest file .

Now you have to put icon inside a drawable folder which is inside res folder

Your path follow look like  :res>>>>drawable >>>icon.png

[image]

In case of Kivy  it become twice eaiser

Your icon path needs to be either absolute or relative to your application file. So if your directory structure looks like this:

my_app/
├── app.py
└── things
    └── images
        └── my_icon.png

```
class MyApp:
    def build(self):
        self.icon = r'C:\Users\you\path\to\my_app\things\images\my_icon.png'
self.icon = r'things\images\my_icon.png'
```